blender does not show objects when rendering on GPU
I have an apple m3 video card. When I launched blender for the first time everything worked, but then crashed after a minute. It didn't work anymore. I tried reinstalling - it didn't change anything.
The computer was purchased from an apple store a month ago.
What could be the problem?
I tried to go through the settings using videos from YouTube, but everything was fine. These videos are old enough that the settings from the video do not exist[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/rWqgFykZ.jpg)
